# How to add start time variable to Lite YouTube Embed code created by Amit Agarwal

Tags: youtube, embed

I use Amit Agarwal code from https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/ in my website to lite embeded youtube video.

Is there any way to add start time to the script so that I could load each video with different start time.

```html
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="VIDEO_ID" start-id="TIME"></div>
```

His complete script are as follows:

```html
<script>
 
  function labnolIframe(div) {

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + div.dataset.id + '?autoplay=1&rel=0');

    iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');

    iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '1');

    iframe.setAttribute('allow', 'accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture');

    div.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, div);

  }


  function initYouTubeVideos() {

    var playerElements = document.getElementsByClassName('youtube-player');

    for (var n = 0; n < playerElements.length; n++) {

      var videoId = playerElements[n].dataset.id;

      var div = document.createElement('div');

      div.setAttribute('data-id', videoId);

      var thumbNode = document.createElement('img');

      thumbNode.src='//i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/hqdefault.jpg'.replace('ID', videoId);

      div.appendChild(thumbNode);

      var playButton = document.createElement('div');

      playButton.setAttribute('class', 'play');

      div.appendChild(playButton);

      div.onclick = function () {

        labnolIframe(this);

      };

      playerElements[n].appendChild(div);

    }

  }


  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initYouTubeVideos);

</script>
```

I have added timeId var into the mix hoping that I could use start-id value to let embed video to start at specific time.  It still start at 0 sec of the video.

```js
 function labnolIframe(div) {

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + div.dataset.id + '?start='+ div.dataset.id + '&autoplay=1&rel=0');

    iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');

    iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '1');

    iframe.setAttribute('allow', 'accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture');

    div.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, div);

  }


  function initYouTubeVideos() {

    var playerElements = document.getElementsByClassName('youtube-player');

    for (var n = 0; n < playerElements.length; n++) {

      var videoId = playerElements[n].dataset.id;

      var timeId = playerElements[n].dataset.id;

      var div = document.createElement('div');

      div.setAttribute('data-id', videoId);

      div.setAttribute('start-id', timeId);

      var thumbNode = document.createElement('img');

      thumbNode.src = '//i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/hqdefault.jpg'.replace('ID', videoId);

      div.appendChild(thumbNode);

      var playButton = document.createElement('div');

      playButton.setAttribute('class', 'play');

      div.appendChild(playButton);

      div.onclick = function () {

        labnolIframe(this);

      };

      playerElements[n].appendChild(div);

    }

  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initYouTubeVideos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```js
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + div.dataset.id + '?autoplay=1&rel=0');
```

to:

```js
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + div.dataset.id + '?start=YOUR_START_TIME_IN_SECONDS&autoplay=1&rel=0');
```

Note the added `start=YOUR_START_TIME_IN_SECONDS&` in the URL.

Comment: I need a variable for start time or each video, so the above changes will make every video to start at the set time.

````
e.g. 
Embed 1 of video 1
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="VIDEO_ID 1" start-id="122"></div>

Embed 2 of video 1
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="VIDEO_ID 1" start-id="430"></div>

Embed 3 of video 2
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="VIDEO_ID 2" start-id="214"></div>
````

Comment: Then just use another parameter as `div.dataset.id` to set the starting time of your video...

Comment: I tried adding `div.setAttribute('start-id', timeId);` to the code and call it in `div class` but it doesn't seems to work.  Hope anyone can help point out my mistake.  Thanks in advance.